# 1950 children's science fiction story

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, mars

I once read a 1950s children's science fiction story set on Mars. It was about a family that had just moved there, and befriended a colonial kid. They lived under a dome, and adopted a Martian animal with red, white, and blue hair, which they named "Yank." Anyone have any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 5):

This is Richard M. Elam's 1953 'Young Visitor to Mars'. The family is from Earth, they live in a domed house, the teen-age hero makes friends with a Martian colonist his own age and they have a red-white-and-blue pet named 'Yank'. It is available on Project Gutenberg ([here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/60133/60133-h/60133-h.htm)) and there are cheap copies on places like ebay.

Comment: If it's available on Project Gutenberg can you add a link?

Comment: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/60133/60133-h/60133-h.htm

Answer (score 4):

Some of the details don't quite match. But, this reminds me a little bit of the 1960  Robert Silverberg novel [Lost Race of Mars](http://www.papergreat.com/2014/10/scholastic-fest-1-lost-race-of-mars.html)

Points that match:

I once read a 1950s children's science fiction story set on Mars.

> Partial check:  Story is set on Mars. Book published in 1960

It was about a family that had just moved there,

> Check. The story is about Sally and Jim, ages 11 and 12 or thereabouts ("Jim, "six and a half" Martian years, and Sally, six" Martian years) along with their parents who move to Mars.

and befriended a colonial kid. They lived under a dome,

> Check. Though many of the Martian children do not originally like Jim and Sally.

and adopted a Martian animal with red, white, and blue hair, which they named "Yank."

> Partial check. They adopt a Martian animal as a pet. However, they call him "Mitten" for "Mars Kitten".

[Book review](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8535126-lost-race-of-mars)

Comment: Wow, that's really close. I was pretty sure we had it until that last line. It might still be. I"ll check in to it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not it. The more I think about it, I'm pretty certain the original had a couple mediocre illustrations in it, one including "Yank" dancing